# SIPP Scenario (version 1.0 don't send digits)

Tags: sipp

Folks, 
I am trying to make calls to test a IVR Machine with SIPP.
First, I am using the Sipp v1.0 final version. But this version does not have support to send digits to IVR Machine. So system is unable to answer calls.
I tested using other versions too.

Here is my scenario:

```
<!DOCTYPE scenario SYSTEM "sipp.dtd">

<scenario name="Basic Sipstone UAC">

<send>

<![CDATA[

INVITE sip:12053@10.0.8.67 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.4.147:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK386088
From: "sipp" <sip:11958251026@10.0.4.147:5070>;tag=8808
To: <sip:12053@10.0.8.67>
Call-ID: 1510678743-6088-NVT4147@10.0.4.147
CSeq: 45 INVITE

Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: NCH Software Express Talk 4.28
Contact: <sip:11958251026@10.0.4.147:5060>
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, INFO, REFER, NOTIFY
Supported: replaces
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 328
v=0
o=NCHSoftware-Talk 1510678729 1510678743 IN IP4 10.0.4.147
s=Express Talk Call
c=IN IP4 10.0.4.147
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 96 3 13 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:96 G726-32/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=sendrecv

]]>

</send>

<recv response="100" optional="true">
</recv>

<recv response="180" optional="true">
</recv>

<recv response="183" optional="true">
</recv>

<recv response="200">
</recv>

<send>

<![CDATA[

ACK sip:12053@10.0.8.67:5060;user=phone SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.4.147:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK396088
To: <sip:12053@10.0.8.67>;tag=7831-08A1
From: "sipp" <sip:11958251026@10.0.4.147:5070>;tag=8808
Call-ID: 1510678743-6088-NVT4147@10.0.4.147
CSeq: 45 ACK      
Max-Forwards: 20
User-Agent: NCH Software Express Talk 4.28
Content-Length: 0

]]>

</send>
<nop>
<action>
<exec play_pcap_audio="pcap/g711a.pcap"/>
</action>
</nop>
<pause milliseconds="8000"/>
<nop>
<action>
<exec play_pcap_audio="pcap/dtmf_2833_1.pcap"/>
</action>
</nop>
<pause milliseconds="3000"/>
<send>
<![CDATA[
BYE sip:12053@10.0.8.67:5060;user=phone SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.4.147:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK26088
From: "sipp" <sip:11958251026@10.0.4.147:5070>;tag=8795
To: <sip:12053@10.0.8.67>;tag=7831-2E51
Call-ID: 1510678730-6088-NVT4147@10.0.4.147
CSeq: 107 BYE
Max-Forwards: 20
Subject: Performance Test
Content-Length: 0
]]>
</send>
<recv response="200" crlf="true">
</recv>
<ResponseTimeRepartition value="10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 150, 200"/>
<CallLengthRepartition value="10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000"/>
</scenario>
```

But, the answer is that (when I am using de version 1.0):

> 2017-11-16 19:31:46: Unknown element 'nop' in xml scenario file.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

SIPP can do complex SIP scripts but it is very limited for Voice interactions...

If you plan to test the IVR with Voice/DTMF interactions, try with Asterisk.
You can use a Dialer Script (We can provide one) to apply to your IVR a charge, with a Dialpan you can create complex scripting (with random).

Comment: I'm calling from SIPP and Softphone to a ivr machine. When I call through the softphone, I get the 200 and I send the ACK. When I call through the sipp using the scenario below, I get a lot of 200 but ACK is not sent by sipp.
Can someone help me with this case? Is there a mistake in the scenario I created? please help me.

Comment: <send>
    <![CDATA[

      ACK sip:12053@10.0.8.67:5060;user=phone SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.4.147:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK19292
   To: <sip:12053@10.0.8.67>;tag=7831-8D63
   From: "g" <sip:11958251026@10.0.4.147:5070>;tag=9471
   Call-ID: 1510678743-6088-NVT4147@10.0.4.147
   CSeq: 888 INVITE
      Max-Forwards: 20
   User-Agent: NCH Software Express Talk 4.28
   Content-Length: 0
   
    ]]>
  </send>